# Using Linq to check if a boolean expression is true

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to use linq to check if one of multiple logic statements return true.

So far I've tried the following:

```
winningCombinations = new[,] 
    {
        {1,2,3},
        {4,5,6},
        {7,8,9},
        {1,4,7},
        {1,4,7},
        {3,6,9},
        {1,5,9},
        {3,5,7}
    };
if (Enumerable.Range(0,7).Where(x => this.contentOf(winningCombinations[x,0]) == this.contentOf(winningCombinations[x,1]) && 
                                     this.contentOf(winningCombinations[x,1]) == this.contentOf(winningCombinations[x,2]))
                                     .Select(x => true).FirstOrDefault(x => x))
    {
        _isDone = true;
        _game.wonBy(_turnOf);
    }
```

Basically contentOf() require an Index as a parameter and return a char value.
My question is, is there a way to make my code work? I'd like to use the coordinates contained in "winningCombinations" to check if there is a winningCombination on my grid (3 identical characters), preferably using Linq.

Comment: You should describe what the problem is with your current approach and probably post the code to contentOf() as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly unclear on what you're trying for, but it *sounds* like [`IEnumerable.Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx) should do what you want.

```
if (Enumerable.Range(0,7)
              .Any(x => this.contentOf(winningCombinations[x,0]) == this.contentOf(winningCombinations[x,1]) && 
                        this.contentOf(winningCombinations[x,1]) == this.contentOf(winningCombinations[x,2]))
{
    _isDone = true;
    _game.wonBy(_turnOf);
}
```

This is pretty self-explanatory, but essentially the goal is to find *any* sets for which the result it true. If it finds one, it returns `true` and jumps into the `if` block. If it looks through the full array and doesn't find any matches, it will return `false`.

---

If you're looking for even more LINQ, and who isn't, this is *arguably* cleaner. Arguably.

```
if (Enumerable.Range(0, winningCombinations.GetLength(0))
              .Select(c => Enumerable.Range(0, winningCombinations.GetLength(1)
                                     .Select(x => this.contentOf(winningCombinations[c, x])
              .Any(x => !x.Distinct().Skip(1).Any())
{
    _isDone = true;
    _game.wonBy(_turnOf);
}
```

Broken up a bit,

```
// Get the indexes for of the array
var ys = Enumerable.Range(0, winningCombinations.GetLength(0));
var xs = Enumerable.Range(0, winningCombinations.GetLength(1));

// Select the values at each index, becomes a collection of collections
var vals = ys.Select(y => xs.Select(x => this.contentOf(winningCombinations[y, x]));

// Discover whether at least one of the sets has exactly one value contained.
return vals.Any(c => !x.Distinct().Skip(1).Any())
```